# Projectile with Friction

Tags: integration, classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

I am trying to find the optimal angle for a projectile to travel a maximum horizontal distance.

I've been given the projection has mass $1kg$ and initial velocity $150m/s$. The equation for air resistance I'm using is
$$ F_{air} = - k|v|^2 $$

where $k = 0.001$

I'm currently trying to use the following equation to find the horizontal distance:

$$ \int v_x dt = \int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{v_o\cos(\theta)} + \frac{kt}{m}} dt  $$

but I'm unsure what values to integrate between on the right integral as I do not know the time it will take the projectile to land.

Please can someone give me a hint on what I should do next.

Comment: If the ground is flat, you need to solve for $y(t)=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, the ground is flat. Thank you

Comment: @YvesDaoust So $\int v_x dt = 0$ and then rearrange to find $\theta$?

Comment: No. $\int v_y\,dt=0$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust But I have no equations involving $v_y$??

Comment: Well, you have to.